# SF report download as .xls wont open in Excel/ Access

Tags: reporting, data

I am running a report in SF then trying to download as UTF8 / .XLS format.

[image]

Then when I try to open in Excel / import to Access I get the following warning message:
[image]

It seems that the file has the wrong MIME type and it thinks its an HTML doc not .xls

Have other people encountered this or is there a setting I can change to rectify this?  Google'ing proved fruitless.

Thanks.

Comment: The .xls Picklist choice actually generates an html file with an .xls extension.  Excel knows how to open html files that present as tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it in Excel first and then save it. If you still have trouble try the CSV format.

Comment: thanks I have been doing that.  I just wondered if there was something such as a setting I was missing.  It just seemed strange that SF would generate an Excel download that wasn't 'instantly' usable via Excel...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with some HTML files labeled as .xls.  I think it is the HTML formatting.  I opened the file in [Web Expression 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36179) (free) and saved then opened it in Excel and it worked perfectly.